# ANTLR Recursion

Tags: antlr

When I execute the below grammar with the input (3), I obtain this parse tree:

[image]

It doesn't recognize the closing parentheses. What might be the problem

```
term 
    :  IDENT | '(' term ')'  | INTEGER
    ;

INTEGER : '0'..'9'+;
IDENT : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9')*;
WS : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n' | '\f')+{$channel = HIDDEN;};
```

Comment: I'm afraid your image link isn't working for me, so I can't really tell what behaviour you're seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no problem with your grammar. It looks like you're using the Eclipse ANTLR-plugin, which in its turn uses the interpreter from ANTLRWorks. This interpreter is notoriously buggy: if you get unexpected behavior, always run a manual test, or use ANTLRWorks' debugger, which debugs the input `"(3)"` like this:

[image]

To start the debugger in ANTLRWors, choose menu **Run >> Debug**, or press <kbd>CTL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be a bug in the UI. I think the parser is seeing the ). Have you tried invoking the parser from Java?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    throws Exception
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ANTLRStringStream strstrm = new ANTLRStringStream("(3)");
    ffLexer lex = new ffLexer(strstrm);
    CommonTokenStream tokStrm = new CommonTokenStream(lex);
    ffParser prs = new ffParser(tokStrm);
    prs.term();

}
```

If you add an action to your term rule:

```
term 
    :  IDENT | a='('   term b=')'  {System.out.println($a.text + " " + $b.text);} | INTEGER
    ;
```

You should get the output

```
( )
```

Also, if you create another parser rule:

```
prog: term+;
```

and then give the input `(3)(4)(5)` the parse tree is as expected